# Docker certificates with volume

Tags: docker, ubuntu, volume

I need to share my docker machine certs with container, so I used volume for it. Unfortunately it seems doesn't work as I expected because container doesn't find this files.

It's problem existing on my linux (Ubuntu) machine. On my macOS system everything looks fine. My approach works correctly and the file exists. I tried to modify path but it wasn't help.

start-service.sh

```
docker build -t api-gateway-service .
docker run --name api-gateway-service -v /<absolute path to .docker>/machine/machines/manager1:/certs --net='host' --env-file env -d api-gateway-service
```

env

```
DOCKER_CERT_PATH=/certs
```

config.js

```js
const certDir = process.env.DOCKER_CERT_PATH

const dockerSettings = {
  protocol: 'https',
  host: machine.substr(machine.indexOf(':', 0) + 3, machine.indexOf(':', 6) - 6),
  port: parseInt(machine.substr(-4), 10),
  checkServerIdentity: false,
  ca: fs.readFileSync(certDir + '/ca.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync(certDir + '/cert.pem'),
  key: fs.readFileSync(certDir + '/key.pem'),
  version: 'v1.25'
}
```

I created container and application trying to get certs from mounted volume. But then throws error with "Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/certs/ca.pem'" so something went wrong with it.

Comment: Ubuntu systems don't generally use a separate Docker VM, and there aren't usually TLS certificates to get this way.  Making the Docker socket network-accessible is a _massive_ security exposure and it's very unusual to allow HTTPS access to it over the network.

Comment: Is there any possibility to achieve this goal? I'm following that guide [link] (https://medium.com/@cramirez92/build-a-nodejs-cinema-booking-microservice-and-deploying-it-with-docker-part-3-9c384e21fbe0) but for performance purpose i need to change machine.

Comment: The usual approach is to bind-mount the Docker socket `/var/run/docker.sock` into the container.  This will let you perform any Docker operations on the same host as the container.  Remember that "any Docker operations" implies unrestricted root-level access on the host.